# Storing an array in firebase

Tags: javascript, angular

i want to store an array of components created dynamically with angular into a firebase collection but  i cannot resolve this error

'ERROR FirebaseError: Function CollectionReference.add() requires its first argument to be of type object, but it was: an array'
that's my implementation

```
  componentscollection: AngularFirestoreCollection;
  componentclass = [];

   constructor(private db: AngularFirestore...){
    this.componentscollection = db.collection('componentclass')
   } 

   //that's where am adding the components into the array 
     addComponent(componentClass: ComponentFactory<any>, target) {
         let componentRef: ComponentRef<any> = this.container.createComponent(componentClass);
         this.componentclass.push(componentClass)
      }



      //function that will add the array of components into the database 
      savemockup(){

       this.componentscollection.add(this.componentclass); }
```

When calling the method savemockup() this  error occured .

Comment: I think you should say `componentscollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<ComponentFactory<any>>;` when you declare the collection

Comment: I tried to specify the type but the same error occured

Comment: You should iterate thru the array and add each item individually: `this.componentclass.forEach(o => this.componentscollection.add(o));`

Comment: i tried it but i got this error 'Function DocumentReference.set() called with invalid data. Nested arrays are not supported'

Comment: not enough info to understand. Is `DocumentReferece.set()` yours? Or firebase? Maybe you need to share more code.